# LINQ to SQL : assign column alias name and set value

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

In C# I write linq I want to return `IEnumerable<DataRow>` with column with name `isedit` and want to set `isedit`

```
innerResult.Select(f => new { isedit = (APS_WorkFlow_Activities).Contains(f.Field<Guid>("ActivityI‌​D")) ? false : true });
```

but `isedit` doesn't get set

Comment: What you mean doesn't create... Please better explain what you are trying to do and what isn't working

Comment: And what do you mean by "must create column"? You're just performing a query here. Please try to explain your issue in more detail

Comment: in c# I write linq I want to return IEnumerable<DataRow> with column with name isedit and want tu set is edit

Comment: innerResult.Select(f => new
                         {
                           isedit  =(APS_WorkFlow_Activities).Contains(f.Field<Guid>("ActivityID")) ? false : true
                         });

Comment: but isedit doesn't set

Comment: This returns `IEnumerable<anonymousobject>` not `IEnumerable<DataRow>`